# Right join two datasets in R not working with dplyr and base R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, time-series

Hopefully this will be an easy fix because for the life of me, I can't figure out what's going wrong.

Here's the dput of two dataframes:

```
dput(bla)
structure(list(date = structure(c(8552, 8582, 8613, 8644, 8674, 
8705, 8735, 8766, 8797, 8825, 8856, 8886, 8917, 8947, 8978, 9009, 
9039, 9070, 9100, 9131, 9162, 9190, 9221, 9251, 9282, 9312, 9343, 
9374, 9404, 9435, 9465, 9496, 9527, 9556, 9587, 9617, 9648, 9678, 
9709, 9740, 9770, 9801, 9831, 9862, 9893, 9921, 9952, 9982, 10013, 
10043, 10074, 10105, 10135, 10166, 10196, 10227, 10258, 10286, 
10317, 10347, 10378, 10408, 10439, 10470, 10500, 10531, 10561, 
10592, 10623, 10651, 10682, 10712, 10743, 10773, 10804, 10835, 
10865, 10896, 10926, 10957, 10988, 11017, 11048, 11078, 11109, 
11139, 11170, 11201, 11231, 11262, 11292, 11323, 11354, 11382, 
11413, 11443, 11474, 11504, 11535, 11566, 11596, 11627, 11657, 
11688, 11719, 11747, 11778, 11808, 11839, 11869, 11900, 11931, 
11961, 11992, 12022, 12053, 12084, 12112, 12143, 12173, 12204, 
12234, 12265, 12296, 12326, 12357, 12387, 12418, 12449, 12478, 
12509, 12539, 12570, 12600, 12631, 12662, 12692, 12723, 12753, 
12784, 12815, 12843, 12874, 12904, 12935, 12965, 12996, 13027, 
13057, 13088, 13118, 13149, 13180, 13208, 13239, 13269, 13300, 
13330, 13361, 13392, 13422, 13453, 13483, 13514, 13545, 13573, 
13604, 13634, 13665, 13695, 13726, 13757, 13787, 13818, 13848, 
13879, 13910, 13939, 13970, 14000, 14031, 14061, 14092, 14123, 
14153, 14184, 14214, 14245, 14276, 14304, 14335, 14365, 14396, 
14426, 14457, 14488, 14518, 14549, 14579, 14610, 14641, 14669, 
14700, 14730, 14761, 14791, 14822, 14853, 14883, 14914, 14944, 
14975, 15006, 15034, 15065, 15095, 15126, 15156, 15187, 15218, 
15248, 15279, 15309, 15340, 15371, 15400, 15431, 15461, 15492, 
15522, 15553, 15584, 15614, 15645, 15675, 15706, 15737, 15765, 
15796, 15826, 15857, 15887, 15918, 15949, 15979, 16010, 16040, 
16071, 16102, 16130, 16161, 16191, 16222, 16252, 16283, 16314, 
16344, 16375, 16405, 16436, 16467, 16495, 16526, 16556, 16587, 
16617, 16648, 16679, 16709, 16740, 16770, 16801, 16832, 16861, 
16892, 16922, 16953, 16983, 17014, 17045, 17075, 17106, 17136, 
17167, 17198, 17226, 17257, 17287, 17318, 17348, 17379, 17410, 
17440, 17471, 17501, 17532, 17563, 17591, 17622, 17652), class = "Date"), 
    AverageTemp = c(16.44, 15.7230769230769, 16.4484358974359, 
    16.2202307692308, 15.6025, 16.4114423076923, 16.7097115384615, 
    16.32125, 16.7625, 16.8855769230769, 17.864358974359, 18.4282692307692, 
    17.5625, 16.9068269230769, 17.1636730769231, 16.8279230769231, 
    17.09125, 17.8747916666667, 17.2025, 16.9225, 17, 17.75, 
    17.85, 17.3663461538462, 17.4355769230769, 16.8797115384615, 
    17.0658717948718, 17.2979230769231, 17.2128205128205, 17.78225, 
    17.48, 16.9457051282051, 18.535, 18.5871634615385, 17.7346153846154, 
    18.214188034188, 16.7875, 16.6706196581197, 17.103125, 17.3691346153846, 
    17.8264423076923, 16.4920192307692, 16.8905128205128, 16.9484615384615, 
    17.350641025641, 17.9035096153846, 18.1136363636364, 18.0958, 
    18.125, 17.3089871794872, 17.3978205128205, 17.8078985507246, 
    17.6580384615385, 17.7281643356643, 17.3222222222222, 17.6125555555556, 
    18.4708333333333, 18.9261363636364, 18.3610714285714, 18.2842857142857, 
    17.8921428571423, 17.5, 18.9776818181818, 18.2313068181818, 
    18.5352272727273, 18.2314393939394, 16.8462121212121, 17.5330452568202, 
    16.5851136363636, 18.3415151515152, 19.0620454545455, 17.5744047619048, 
    16.7176308539945, 16.6407407407407, 16.7227272727273, 16.4184848484848, 
    17.5290598290598, 17.1817965367965, 16.4547619047619, 15.9484848484848, 
    15.6835902503294, 16.0388865398168, 17.0166666666667, 17.5905555555556, 
    16.4290088383838, 16.2997452016069, 16.1557023172906, 16.7221212121212, 
    16.857196969697, 17.3215277777778, 16.5125, 16.0752525252525, 
    15.5828743589744, 16.6117845117845, 17.9668930686172, 17.5651666666667, 
    16.3064442224442, 16.2763888888889, 17.650505050505, 16.8803872053872, 
    17.3298611111111, 17.3772443181818, 17.0242424242424, 16.8111111111111, 
    16.8055555555556, 17.232601010101, 17.8261363636364, 17.3753787878788, 
    16.5777272727273, 15.8893939393939, 16.9522435897436, 16.5363636363636, 
    16.6034090909091, 17.2667929292929, 18.0511363636364, 17.5534090909091, 
    16.4551136363636, 17.23125, 17.5136363636364, 17.8482954545455, 
    16.9869318181818, 16.4244318181818, 17.125, 16.8022727272727, 
    17.4343006993007, 17.2990909090909, 17.1961538461538, 17.009375, 
    16.9174747474747, 17.2710227272727, 17.6715909090909, 17.4818181818182, 
    15.9962121212121, 16.5631818181818, 16.6078349282297, 17.1787878787879, 
    17.0653409090909, 17.4431818181818, 17.4880681818182, 15.0918803418803, 
    16.7741339869281, 17.4332792207792, 17.7990981240981, 18.0886363636364, 
    16.8297619047619, 16.6851973684211, 17.2556818181818, 17.0295454545455, 
    16.8240909090909, 16.7538770053476, 16.2579545454545, 15.9655757575758, 
    17.1280753968254, 17.7519191919192, 17.4414335664336, 17.4557954545455, 
    16.1622115384615, 16.8327651515152, 16.9667613636364, 16.672798573975, 
    16.9659090909091, 17.0818181818182, 17.1822027972028, 17.8164884135472, 
    17.4545454545455, 16.7771212121212, 17.8238636363636, 17.7005244755245, 
    16.7160984848485, 16.341754756871, 16.6440025252525, 16.9829545454545, 
    16.6630555555556, 19.1123467230444, 19.3261363636364, 17.7603021978022, 
    18.8059107142857, 18.2065559440559, 18.25, 16.965, 18.0582115800866, 
    17.2105637254902, 18.6762012987013, 18.4136363636364, 18.2600378787879, 
    18.0003496503497, 17.9288825757576, 17.959375, 18.5164772727273, 
    18.4772727272727, 18.2170454545455, 18.90625, 17.8438112745084, 
    16.7813725490196, 17.2660256410256, 17.0635542929293, 17.2422902097902, 
    17.1887820512821, 16.1727941176471, 16.0860294117647, 18.3868181818182, 
    18.0298076923077, 18.7031536293164, 18.3659090909091, 18.625, 
    16.7256818181818, 17.2232600732601, 18.3319639192886, 17.9238636363636, 
    17.9799422799423, 16.5837121212121, 16.100952540107, 16.9387019230769, 
    17.3568181818182, 17.1753146853147, 17.1159090909091, 18.1145833333333, 
    16.8415170940171, 16.9133597285068, 17.6888034188034, 17.1259793447293, 
    17.384655448718, 16.7841346153846, 16.2973468660969, 16.1201495726496, 
    17.5849893162393, 18.2456018518519, 18.0254807692308, 17.4643233618234, 
    17.1731532356532, 17.5413283475783, 17.7156695156695, 17.5869255189255, 
    17.6197802197802, 17.1997996794872, 17.6756588319088, 18.048433048433, 
    18.5746082621083, 19.1991987179487, 18.6432081807082, 17.7431185134298, 
    16.8430288461538, 17.4325367647059, 17.314707977208, 17.5010576923077, 
    17.9123219373219, 17.4, 17.5033333333333, 17.8433333333333, 
    18.9353846153846, 18.6049679487179, 17.1923076923077, 17.3169136500756, 
    17.4415196078431, 17.6505057932264, 17.2357352941176, 17.9955326484661, 
    17.5959523809524, 17.5952941176471, 16.9622171945701, 18.2641666666667, 
    17.3842124183007, 18.8371301247772, 18.2442091503268, 17.8693572984749, 
    17.4261783559578, 17.8408721670486, 18.0430294117647, 17.5234615384615, 
    18.7757894736842, 18.0545833333333, 18.3861029411765, 17.2286764705882, 
    19.1830882352941, 18.9825490196078, 19.399375, 18.8928921568627, 
    17.379375, 17.8381315789474, 18.9048611111111, 18.32625, 
    18.5, 17.1804924242424, 17.165, 19.0856617647059, 18.6882066993464, 
    18.949358974359, 18.2374264705882, 17.9036554621849, 17.7655882352941, 
    18.0464795008913, 18.5610902795469, 19.0757010582011, 18.0125, 
    17.0503365384615, 17.4858707264957, 18.0303062678063, 19.0284455128205, 
    18.0894444444444, 18.4038461538462)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-300L))
```

and then the last dataframe:

```
dput(StreamsTempArimadf)
structure(list(x = c(16.4235600120089, 16.3162100053303, 16.0070043862204, 
16.3293829899719, 16.1716209581513, 15.9265717739553, 16.3090255869541, 
16.4439403499551, 16.3183999455157, 16.5396837132066, 16.6811003351237, 
17.1819034280054, 17.4190971140018, 16.9507474339223, 16.9665291179653, 
16.9442313905304, 16.6702713669365, 17.0986393517563, 17.4571404047562, 
17.0412727081225, 17.0800866201236, 17.0991637091277, 17.6890431545816, 
17.7743643985327, 17.2391733379432, 17.114436449957, 17.1642136645732, 
17.0419872079513, 17.1508300146882, 17.457457700922, 17.4906544182104, 
17.2811736236672, 17.1873524547541, 18.080784279529, 18.2710625781783, 
17.8089224014503, 17.9005244899158, 17.0590129809746, 17.1527561837507, 
17.2736999465254, 17.4147893614722, 17.882339235762, 16.9499273482652, 
17.0004563504348, 17.4465111341327, 17.5933858446829, 17.6101923201963, 
17.8276978662699, 17.5352907254964, 17.5981453854789, 17.4319527121414, 
17.5127750041499, 17.7472485403081, 17.4518868116148, 17.6165920594086, 
17.3383202176906, 17.8726838287055, 18.2516671157085, 18.3401983819894, 
18.2441420462271, 17.9464348476102, 17.6826435705472, 17.6862560770876, 
18.4800625152448, 18.163416057388, 18.0819846655268, 18.0427811729686, 
17.4764506525787, 17.9766180508654, 17.5739583565098, 18.1587370200372, 
18.5374092492432, 17.7986532863903, 17.166741098103, 17.5155838070475, 
17.2442836783546, 17.1236998155698, 17.5184790300461, 16.996418356209, 
17.0114773309173, 16.575156984327, 16.8769092269045, 16.8126639232741, 
16.8417680024193, 17.008800908992, 16.5201792179267, 16.7568646770597, 
16.3400269198786, 16.9687268157554, 16.7654880256296, 16.6459894006643, 
16.4842769700434, 16.0501433720352, 16.2853420617816, 16.9061560279575, 
17.266910321255, 16.7867841578962, 16.3707541665658, 16.3484674988731, 
17.082104538038, 16.9624091182207, 17.1275367937929, 16.8485908221693, 
16.6628004673368, 16.5115046382591, 16.8870014133329, 17.443488126818, 
17.5394616505467, 16.865893242366, 16.6868770380703, 16.6347519544701, 
16.8946909796982, 16.850518851335, 16.8961157367574, 16.933012066422, 
17.3040994409743, 17.0980909355685, 16.9206949659294, 17.5108937191278, 
17.30914581016, 17.1599737380471, 16.8068898195722, 17.0881896883499, 
16.9526719375552, 16.9938336821843, 17.3986485098226, 17.3896926360502, 
17.1411267914391, 16.8691444341467, 17.1780863554545, 17.3941654126018, 
17.5070218752187, 17.1042209689241, 16.3080476751907, 16.9838783206861, 
16.6900948240033, 17.1634740495749, 17.1377962741821, 17.3935169959911, 
17.2485239918743, 15.9559293105117, 16.9753943261052, 17.3289942756477, 
17.4788165790681, 17.1650184110551, 16.8604463188829, 16.9090227533541, 
17.1813633778358, 17.1377480680697, 17.0557152944054, 16.9681837063859, 
16.1490033007953, 16.5905967758405, 17.1597818837683, 17.5281678796462, 
17.3739134310423, 16.8387058556393, 16.5488818369602, 16.942188477582, 
16.9939361489774, 16.7656502810222, 16.9728586408147, 16.9068702063248, 
16.5299085735022, 17.6336612822056, 17.5192032114855, 17.0848046317387, 
17.6140853064621, 17.0496648877158, 16.9563207097481, 16.8341749877878, 
16.7776295686818, 16.9968091767582, 16.8436919790286, 17.936060569165, 
18.2683861830887, 17.7061409177559, 18.1267693252196, 18.0981327112525, 
18.0368665422974, 17.0058103665895, 17.7317804064389, 17.4328473056823, 
18.1059872656293, 18.0066199736901, 18.5420197895817, 18.2386625158068, 
17.920093236398, 18.1943774528721, 18.1246439107403, 18.4319137019451, 
17.9319262189137, 18.4794408379272, 17.7301407084081, 17.7032958421153, 
17.7026697296431, 17.4723762038505, 17.9213412975878, 17.7090050046618, 
16.8949207799177, 17.1892475487151, 17.958904648503, 17.8222954828579, 
18.1149099184821, 17.992723406567, 17.7888291578949, 17.4651360067617, 
17.4028671755571, 17.9665614655481, 17.7439955761655, 17.5733730183845, 
17.0180175718416, 17.3540421001795, 17.3164554624378, 17.6172420799226, 
17.5098760296836, 17.3035492813519, 17.2100024772565, 17.1120386222669, 
17.2555537061401, 17.4556863536271, 17.2333391894539, 16.8606341604694, 
16.6871851112957, 17.0945647897169, 16.7369120033751, 17.4470612186725, 
17.6773462550042, 17.920581660371, 16.9467628141399, 17.1944096236417, 
17.6946918359649, 17.4284279757113, 17.5365237767232, 17.1559098825923, 
16.9516013865081, 17.3850949470463, 17.9489417716113, 18.1744911646621, 
18.4115595308646, 18.293388692048, 17.5894365880081, 17.3746476932594, 
17.7437796480596, 17.4636252645181, 17.6394593290919, 17.6065098302595, 
17.4860531818298, 17.5710995180627, 18.0795678954903, 18.6929499387503, 
18.2993721317434, 17.4143107779121, 17.3165509783067, 17.6667429255614, 
17.6750027087088, 17.4900703914578, 17.9204079929319, 17.5119573239623, 
17.6969657837282, 17.4817158838179, 18.3369848754884, 17.8140491121899, 
18.0486541029228, 17.8683594958062, 17.6451875615134, 17.6520340619899, 
17.6602809719005, 18.0188162059647, 17.6773505885273, 18.1824137149234, 
17.8055689616586, 18.3834951647414, 17.6887663116355, 18.8502749568389, 
18.3083359351162, 18.6584460101487, 18.4344112532406, 17.9079866978172, 
18.0004637649642, 18.525949174231, 18.4853600772863, 18.314260475219, 
17.7215331544413, 17.645621916695, 18.8137027079302, 18.7503994471984, 
18.7791794151661, 18.280066624512, 17.7712934998266, 18.0492865337891, 
18.3612291442252, 18.2558483503991, 18.8735748374428, 17.865945718284, 
17.6312767012021, 17.9866072798456, 18.3660623514442, 18.739934865122, 
18.2224175228729)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -300L
))
```

I tried to use this code to place the only column in the second dataframe to the right of the first dataframe:

```
new_dataset <- bla %>% right_join(StreamsTempArimadf, by = c("x"))
```

For some reason this isn't working. I have also tried the `merge()` with this code:

```
new_dataset <- merge(bla, StreamsTempArimadf, by.x="date", by.y="x")
```

And still nothing. What am I doing wrong here? Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You second attempt seems to be trying to join by the columns `date` and `x`, but those don't seem like columns you want to match on. In the *dplyr* version, if the column name isn't the same in both data frames, you have to do `by = c("AverageTemp" = "x")`, for example.

Comment: I think @thc might be correct, though, that you've confused a join with simply attaching a new column.

Answer (score 3):

Joins are for matching two dataframes which may be in different order, but have the same "Key" (the `by` parameter).  Your second data.frame doesn't have `x`, so it can't join.

It seems like you just want to concatenate the columns:

```
new_dataframe <- cbind(bla, StreamsTempArimadf)
```

Comment: Yup, this did it! Thank you!